# How can i raised the event for PrintPage?

Tags: vb.net

how can i raised the event for print page in form 2 while im in form 1

this is the event i want to raised

```
  Public Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage_1(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim dm As New Bitmap(Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, 0, 0)

        Dim aPS As New PageSetupDialog
        aPS.Document = PrintDocument1

    End Sub
```

i want to be able to raised that event here

```
Public Sub printall()
        If txtempname.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("There is no Record to Print")
        Else
            For i = 0 To txtempname.Items.Count - 1
                txtempname.SelectedIndex = i
                getEmployeeInfo()
                getattendance()
                getDeductions()
                getExtraDeductions()
                getLoans()
                calculate()
                printallnote()
                PrintPayslip.payslip()

                'Raised PrintPage event here

                PrintPayslip.print()
                PrintPayslip.Close()
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `PrintDocument1_PrintPage_1` is an event handler. It's not an event. Presumably there is a `PrintPage` method on the `PrintDocument1` object?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you would create a `PageSetupDialog` in the `PrintPage` event handler. That method is there to print a page; that's it, that's all. If you want to display a `PageSetupDialog` then that needs to be done before you call `Print` on the `PrintDocument`, so obviously before the `PrintPage` event handler executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Print` on your `PrintDocument`. That will raise the `BeginPrint` event first and then the `PrintPage` event. As long as you set `e.HasMorePages` to `True` in the event handler, the `PrintPage` event will continue to be raised. Finally, the `EndPrint` event will be raised.

Alternatively, if you call `ShowDialog` on a `PrintPreviewDialog`, the same events will be raised when the user clicks the `Print` button.

Comment: thanks I just check and event is firing, i think there`s nothing wrong with my code just that i ask the wrong question.